# extending an exposed class using boost python

Tags: boost-python

I want to extend a class which has already exposed to python. For example:

snippet 1:

```
class_<DataValueContainer, DataValueContainer::Pointer>( "DataValueContainer" )
    .def( "__len__", &DataValueContainer::Size )
    .def( VariableIndexingPython<DataValueContainer, Variable<std::string> >() )
    .def( VariableIndexingPython<DataValueContainer, Variable<int> >() )
    .def( VariableIndexingPython<DataValueContainer, Variable<double> >() )
    .def( self_ns::str( self ) )
    ;
```

Now in a different place I want to extend python class DataValueContainer, such as:

snippet 2:

```
class_<DataValueContainer, DataValueContainer::Pointer>
    .def( VariableIndexingPython<DataValueContainer, Variable<MyObject> >() )
```

Is it possible to do it using boost.python? The reason I want to do that since the snippet 1 is in the kernel of an existing code and I hesitate to modify it.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible without making some minor modifications to snippet 1, or reimplementing parts of `boost::python::class_`.  When an object of type [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) is instantiated, type initialization and registration occurs within the internals of Boost.Python.  Instantiating `class_` with the same type and arguments will effectively overwrite the previous class object.

In Python, the problem is akin to a type being redefined.  In the example below, the `spam` identifier is used for one type, and then associated with a different type:

```python
>>> class spam:
...     def action1(self): pass
... 
>>> # Redefines spam type.
... class spam:
...     def action2(self): pass
... 
>>> print hasattr(s, "action1")
False
>>> print hasattr(s, "action2")
True
```

Rather than the `spam` type being extended via its identifier:

```python
>>> class spam:
...     def action1(self): pass
... 
>>> # Extend spam type.
... def action2(s): pass
... 
>>> spam.action2 = action2
>>> s = spam()
>>> print hasattr(s, "action1")
True
>>> print hasattr(s, "action2")
True
```

The Boost.Python examples are fairly equivalent to the Python examples.  In this snippet, the `spam` identifier is modified to point to a new type, as a new `class_` instance was instantiated.

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class spam {};
void action1(spam& self) {}
void action2(spam& self) {}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  typedef boost::python::class_<spam> spam_class_type;
  spam_class_type("spam")
    .def("action1", &action1)
    ;

  // Redefines spam type. 
  spam_class_type("spam")
    .def("action2", &action1)
    ;
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for spam already 
            registered; second conversion method ignored.
>>> s = example.spam()
>>> print hasattr(s, "action1")
False
>>> print hasattr(s, "action2")
True
```

To extend the type in Boost.Python, one simply operates on the same `class_` instance:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class spam {};
void action1(spam& self) {}
void action2(spam& self) {}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  typedef boost::python::class_<spam> spam_class_type;
  spam_class_type spam_ = spam_class_type("spam");
  spam_
    .def("action1", &action1)
    ;

  // Extend spam type.
  spam_
    .def("action2", &action2)
    ;
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> s = example.spam()
>>> print hasattr(s, "action1")
True
>>> print hasattr(s, "action2")
True
```